# jquery dataTable pagination css

Tags: jquery, css

I've been searching on how to customize the pagination style but haven't found much on it.

Currently with the below `jquery`, the standard default pagination style is loaded on the table.

```
$('#id_view_student_table').DataTable({
    "pagingType": "simple_numbers",
    "language": {"paginate": {
             "previous": '<i class="fa fa-angle-left" style="color: #27c2a5"></i>',
             "next": '<i class="fa fa-angle-right" style="color: #27c2a5"></i>'
             }
     }
};
```

How do I interact with the `pagination` elements to change the style (through css or jquery)?

### Update

I've added a screen capture to show the elements of the `dataTables_paginate` items.

Thanks to @Birdie Golden for the initial answer on how to interact with the `paginate` elements. Still trying to figure out how to work with `hover` and `current` elements though.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the answer you're looking for but once you've generated the pagination you can inspect that element within the browser window and target the dynamically generated styles.

For example: DataTables outputs the class: .dataTables_wrapper (the container) and .paginate_button (the pagination element). If you wanted to say change the color of the pagination button background and remove the rounded corners you would do something like this in your stylesheet:

```
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button {
    border-radius: 0;
    background: #ff1493;
}
```

[image: DataTables Styling Pagination]

I hope that helps! Good luck :D

Comment: Thanks for this! Let me go try it out, but it looks to be what i'm looking for! What I'm hoping is for a way to interact with the pagination buttons so that I can change the style / color / etc. :)

Comment: My pleasure :) Let me know if it does the trick once you've implemented it.

Comment: Sorry, but I am having some trouble targetting the `disabled` buttons and the `current` buttons. How should I be referencing it? I have tried `.paginate_buttons.disabled` and `.paginate_buttons.current`, ``.paginate_buttons.active` but still unable to target them.

Comment: If you want to link me your website or test environment and describe to me what you want changed I'll see if I can figure it out for you :)

Comment: i'm actually working locally. So don't have an active website or anything yet.. Since I just begin working with django / html .. haha. But normally. Is my way of referencing correct? for `current` and `hover` (with respect to `dataTables jquery`)

Comment: I've added a screen capture of the paginate elements. Does this help you help me? Haha. Thanks again!

Comment: Nope! Lol, but here's why. The pagination classes aren't in your markup, and they won't be because they're dynamically generated. What you have to do is go to your website (or sandbox) where the pagination is being rendered, right click and inspect using the browser developer tools. You'll likely see a bunch of extra classes that are being injected that you don't see in your html markup.

Comment: Once you've identified those injected/dynamic pagination classes, then you can target those classes in your stylesheet. However, its important to remember that pagination is dynamic and doesn't exist in your html markup. I hope that makes sense :)